# Direct image of coherent sheaf coherent with elementary methods

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, sheaf-theory

Let $f:X \to Y$ a proper, affine morphism between Noetherian schemes $X,Y$. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-module. It is well known result that for all $r \ge 0$ the higher direct image $R^r f_*\mathcal{F}$ is a coherent $\mathcal{O}_Y$-module.

The roughly idea is to split the proof in several steps:

1. reduce to affine case $Y=Spec(R)$
2. case $f$ structure map $\mathbb{P}^n_Y \to Y$
3. case $f$ projective
4. general case: use Chow's lemma, Grothendieck spectral sequence and noetherian induction

**Question**: Is it possible to proof the claim in the case $\mathcal{F}=\mathcal{O}_X$ and $r=0$ with more elementary methods; preferably without Chow's lemma and spectral theory, i.e. to show that direct image $f_* \mathcal{O}_X$ is coherent $\mathcal{O}_Y$-module?

by 'elementary' I refer to usual methods from commutative algebra and ring theory. I proceed as follows: $f$ affine and thus as in step 1. I assume $Y=Spec(R), X=Spec(A)$ affine and the induced ring homomorphism by $f$ is $\phi: R \to A$ and our goal is to show that $A$ is coherent $R$-module. This means that $A$ is a quotient of free module $R^n$ for appropriate $n >0$.

As $f$ proper, by definition $A$ is a finitely generated $R$-algebra: this guarantees the existence of a surjection $R[X_1,...,X_n] \to A$ of $R$-algebras. But what we need is that $A$ is finitely generated as $R$-module.

Comment: Proper and affine means finite. Proof can be found in most books.

Comment: yes, that's true. the point is that at most they prove the stronger statement that all higher direct images $R^r f_*\mathcal{F}$ are coherents. and to prove the claim in this generality we need the methods from spectral theory, Chow's lemma and so on as I described above. my concern is if it is possible to prove the special case that $f_* \mathcal{O}_X$ is coherent with more elementary methods

Comment: Do you know ZMT? I mean to prove the statement that @Mohan needs all you need is the fact that proper+quasi-finite implies finite and the fact that an affine+proper variety is finite which follows form the non-relative version of your question. Does this not make you happy?

Comment: Actually, in the non-relative case you don't even need anything fancy. If $X$ is an affine and proper variety it's finite. It suffices to assume that $X$ is geometrically integral since one can easily reduce to this case. Then, the point is that $\mathcal{O}_X(X)$ must be a point since any map $X\to \mathbb{A}^1$ will have proper geometrically integral image which, if one thinks about the closed subsets of $\A^1$, will need to be a point.

Comment: I will think about it. this argument seems much more intuitive then that one I explained above. and yes, since geometric intuition was the main motivation behind this question I'm looking forward to become happy with your argument. Thank you.

Comment: @AlexYoucis: one futher remark on the non-relative case (= $X \to Spec(k)$ in relative language). how do you reduce to " geometrically integral" case? indeed, by definition a variety is reduced and shrinking to a component we can can assume that $X$ is irreducible and thus integral. why you can assume that $X$ is 'geometrically' integral? thus that it stays integral after arbitrary algebraically field extension of the base field?

Comment: @katalaveino because we're trying to show that $\mathcal{O}_X(X)$ is finite. This is equivalent to showing that $\mathcal{O}_X(X)\otimes \overline{k}=\mathcal{O}(X_{\overline{k}})$ is finite. Thus, a better way of saying it would have been "we may as well assume that we're over $\overline{k}$" in which case integrality is the same thing as geometric integrality.

Comment: but the argument that $\mathcal{O}_X(X) \otimes \overline{k}$ finite (over $\overline{k}$) if and and only if $\mathcal{O}_X(X)$ finite over $k$ is a consequence of the  fact that $k \to \overline{k}$ is faithfully flat, is this the argument? in other words the claim cannot be generalized to the case when we replace the base change $\overline{k}$ by arbitrary $k$-algebra $S$?

Comment: @katalaveino Sure, but why does that matter?

Comment: I was just a bit inquisitive on a possibility to generalise it. thank you again for the explanations, that's a really nice viewpoint on properness by reducing it to fiber problems

Comment: @katalaveino Glad I could help.

Comment: Hartshorne, Chapter II, Corollary 5.20 proves that $f_* \mathcal F$ is coherent if $\mathcal F$ is coherent and $f$ is *projective* and both $X, Y$ are of finite type over a field. This only uses that global sections are finitely generated. I don't know if you can avoid Chow's lemma to go from projective to proper.